# Limit Using squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Find the limit of the following function as $x \rightarrow 0$
$$
\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\left(x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7\right)}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}\right)
$$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\left(x^{4}+4 x^{2}+77\right)}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}\right)$

**My approach**,

applying squeeze theorem,

$
-1 \leq \sin \left(\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}\right) \leq 1
$

$-\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4 x^{2}+7}} \leq \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x}}\right) \leq \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7}}$

$\operatorname{Now,}_{\operatorname{limit}_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7}}}=\ _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7}}=0$

*Hence answer is zero.*

**Am I correct?**

Comment: yes, that seems valid, also, you forgot the 3 in the square root when you sqeezed

Comment: oh! yes.But that will not change answer.So I think my approach is correct.Can u tell me any another way to solve this! anyways thanks for correcting me.

Comment: bounded function * 0, sin is bounded and the other expression goes to 0.

Comment: yeah! the final answer must be 0

Answer (score 2):

**Other approach:**

Let $f(x)=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\left(x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7\right)}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}\right)$

We note that $f(x)=-f(-x)$, hence $f$ is odd, we can study it for $x > 0$.

Remembering that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1
$$

we get

$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{\sqrt{\left(x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7\right)}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}\right) &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{\sqrt{\left(x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7\right)}} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}\right)}{\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}} \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}} \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x^{1-\frac{1}{2}}}{3} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0^+}  \frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}\right)}{\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{x}}}\cdot \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x^{4}+4 x^{2}+7\right)}}  \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt x}{3} \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 7} = 0 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 7}= 0
\end{split} 
$$

Comment: very nice thinking!

Comment: Bro ,i just observe. It should be x^(1-1/2) in the 2nd step,anyways answer will remain same!

Comment: Ops, sorry, I did not see it. Now I have fixed the mistake. Thank you!